# Filtering data from XML using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have the following XML file. In this I want to filter all the city names that have employees with age 23.

Kindly help me with a PowerShell script.

I am expecting the answer *"Chennai, Banglore"*.

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
    <customers>
<city name="Chennai">
    <Name>Anand</Name>
    <Id>123</Id>
    <Age>23</Age>
</city>
<city name="Banglore">
    <Name>Arun</Name>
    <Id>321</Id>
    <Age>23</Age>
</city>
<city name="Mumbai">
    <Name>Ashok</Name>
    <Id>1</Id>
    <Age>22</Age>
</city>
```

I have the following code to get the list of city names,

```
[xml]$test = Get-Content D:\test.xml
$names = $test.SelectNodes("/customers/city")
$sno = 0
foreach($node in $names)
{
    $sno++
    $id = $node.getAttribute("name")
    Write-Host $sno $id
}
```

But how do I to filter the data?

Comment: 1) Your XML is malformed, as customers element is not closed. 2) Show some effort in trying to solve the problem and ask for help for specific problem.

Comment: Chennai and Banglore are in two different city-nodes. You won't recieve `Chenai, Banglore` as one value without unless you combine the two values yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Learn about [XPath](http://w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) and how to query XML documents. The key is to use a predicate to filter the data: `/customers/city[Age=23]`. Like so,

```
$names = $test.SelectNodes("/customers/city[Age=23]")
$sno = 0
foreach($node in $names) {
    $sno++
    $id = $node.getAttribute("name")
    Write-Host $sno $id
}
```

Output:

```
1 Chennai
2 Banglore
```

Comment: Note that XPath expressions are case-sensitive. Also, you can directly select the city names without the additional `getAttribute()`: `//city[Age=23]/@name`.